# Firefox image auto-resizing in horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm seeing inconsistencies between Firefox and Chrome/IE with image resizing.

I have a horizontal scrollable div that contains images that are supposed to resize to keep their aspect ratio while filling the available height of the div. This works in Chrome/IE but in Firefox I am seeing extra spacing to the right of each image.

Removing the scroll bar removes the extra spacing, so it seems like Firefox is not recalculating the size of the div correctly with the added scroll bar.

Pure html/css snippet:

```css
.container {
  width: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.innerContainer {
  height: 100%;
}
.imgHolder {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='innerContainer'>
    <div class='imgHolder' style='background:blue'>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300">
    </div>
    <div class='imgHolder' style='background:red'>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300">
    </div>
    <div class='imgHolder' style='background:green'>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
    </div>
    <div class='imgHolder' style='background:red'>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
    </div>
    <div class='imgHolder' style='background:blue'>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
    </div>
    <div class='imgHolder' style='background:green'>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
    </div>
    <div class='imgHolder' style='background:blue'>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The colored backgrounds are added on the divs containing images for clarity. This space should not exist.

Any ideas for fixing this in Firefox?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I've been fighting this all day now but haven't been able to find a solution. I can measure the parent height and set a fixed pixel of each image in JavaScript, but then Edge/IE11 throws up the same problem, and that's a brittle solution.

Comment: Note that this is an [active bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1281713) for this in the Firefox bug tracker, titled **"intrinsic width of parent with overflow-x:scroll not computing correctly with child image with height:100%"**.